# A man married the sister of his widow

Tags: lateral-thinking

A man married the sister of his widow.

How is that ever possible?

Comment: I feel like I must be missing something here.. A man marries someone who dies, and then proceeds to chat up her sister (hopefully not during the funeral). Can someone please explain to me the complication?

Comment: @Shadow The widow isn't the one who's dead, the widow is the spouse of the one who's dead.

Comment: @jmite yep - thanks. That's what I was missing. Obvious now that you've reminded me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> He divorced his wife and then married his ex-wife's sister. After his death, his first wife is his widow's sister...

Comment: @Keelhaul beat you by just 3 minutes, but I accepted your answer as it's more clear. Upvoting both answers, of course.

Comment: This guy didn't marry his widow's sister. He married someone who would later *become* one. 169.

Comment: @dr01"the widow of his sister"? I think you need to flip that around.

Comment: Agree with @Bass, it's stretching common use of language for this to be reasonable. By this logic, it's not uncommon for a man to marry his own widow, but we all know a man marries a woman who later becomes his widow. You might as well say the man marries a corpse, because she'll be one eventually, right?

Comment: @NuclearWang, a corpse marries another corpse, who is the sister of another corpse who was earlier married to the first corpse.  Seems legit.

Comment: Anybody who dies before their spouse "marries their widow".

Answer (score 32):

> They live in France, where posthumous marriage is legal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posthumous_marriage

Comment: The most educating answer!

Answer (score 24):

> He was a priest, and married her to someone else before popping his clogs.

Comment: Beat me to it :-)

Answer (score 18):

Maybe

> He married the sister before marrying his last wife before his death, and not the other way around.

Answer (score 7):

> He was an artificial heart recipient in a country where "death" is defined as the medical state when your heart ceases working.

> This was the case of [Leif Stenberg](http://articles.orlandosentinel.com/1985-07-20/news/0310380006_1_artificial-heart-jarvik-7-leave-the-heart) in Sweden, though he married his wife shortly before the operation and no sister has been involved.

Answer (score 4):

> There was a case recently where a Romanian living in Turkey didn't stay in touch with his wife, who managed to get him [declared dead](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/mar/16/romanian-court-tells-man-he-is-not-alive). He is medically alive, but the Romanian courts have declared themselves unable to cancel his death certificate, so in Romania he is legally dead. If his (ex-)wife has a sister, all he would need to do is to marry her in a country which accepts that he's alive and not committing illegal bigamy (either because it allows bigamy or because it accepts that his first marriage is over).

Answer (score -1):

> He is a mormon and married both sisters.
> Possible Prove: Google unserious boulevard media

Comment: Please make sure to add a spoiler to your solutions, you can do this in the future by adding `>!` in front of the text.

Comment: Google tends to show different results for different people (based on your past searches, among other things) - in the future, consider adding a link to your post instead so we get to the right website :)

Comment: This answer would work with any polygamous culture. See [this article](http://www.beliefnet.com/faiths/2001/02/polygamy-not-as-rare-as-you-may-think.aspx) and [this map](http://metro.co.uk/2015/06/22/where-exactly-is-polygamy-legal-5257418/).

Comment: This answer duplicates several given before it, but fails to explain the underlying logic.